# How to create a custom component with HTML and js?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am using liferay 7 and trying to create a content component which contains a jquery plugin and some css&html? What is the best way to create this?

Comment: wow, this is a really broad question for liferay. when you say component, you mean a portlet? or you are looking for something less specific. if it is really simple you can even use the web content portlet, and just drop in a page. But I can start by telling you that jquery plugin are not too trivial, https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/79089004

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490126/jquery-plugin-in-a-liferay-7-theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use this https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/gradle/apps/npm/jquery-npm-portlet

The README file contains a link to documentation and you can work your way through it to get more inside.

Not that these features are available only in the latest version of Liferay (Liferay-ce-ga5 https://web.liferay.com/web/jamie.sammons/blog/-/blogs/liferay-portal-7-0-ce-ga5-release or DXP FP30+)

Comment: The question is actually more about jquery-UI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088356/how-to-use-jquery-ui-in-liferay-7-page

Comment: It depends on how do you want to bundle it. If you want to develop apps with jquery and jquery-ui the above is the best way. If you just want to slam jquery-ui into the page and have it as a global thing then use the script tag approach. Be aware that if you go with the global path you might run into version problems in the future.

Comment: Actually I want to use a tab control, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Can I use liferay-ui tags inside my ftl file?

Comment: If you just need tabs and you don't care too much about the JS library have look at his. https://alloyui.com/tutorials/tabview. And yes you can use liferay ui tags in ftl. <@liferay_ui["NAME_OF_TAG"]